# Table skipping rows when using a userform for data entry

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create an on call schedule where employees are scheduled for 7 consecutive days on rotation. For example if we have 4 staff, staff member one would be on call for 7 days, then be off for 21 days while staff 2, 3 and 4 are on call, before being back on call for 7 days.

I have the formula for that portion. I am trying to make it dynamic, where employees can be added/ removed and the formula updates to reflect changes.

My plan is to use a table to track employees. I am using a userform to add employees to a table. When an employee is added, they also get a number to be associated with. In the above example of four employees, I would number them 1 to 4 in a separate column.

My issue is, my add to table function skips cells.

My program fills the first row of the table, then skips a cell for the second entry. It then skips 4 cells for the third value, and when I try to enter a 4th or 5th value, the third value is replaced.

```vb
Sub AddDataRow(tableName As String, value As Variant)
    Dim lastRow As Range
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim table As ListObject
    Dim col As Integer

    Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Jobs and Shifts")
    Set table = sheet.ListObjects.Item(tableName)

    'First check if the last row is empty; if not, add a row
    If table.ListRows.Count > 0 Then
        Set lastRow = table.ListRows(table.ListRows.Count).Range
        For col = 1 To lastRow.Columns.Count
            If Trim(CStr(lastRow.Cells(1, col).value)) <> "" Then
                table.ListRows.Add
                Exit For
            End If
        Next col
    Else
        table.ListRows.Add
    End If
    
    'Adds values to the table.  Column 2 should add a number 1 greater then previous
    Set lastRow = table.ListRows(table.ListRows.Count).Range
    lastRow.Cells(table.ListRows.Count, 1).value = value
    lastRow.Cells(table.ListRows.Count, 2).value = lastRow.Cells((lastRow.Count - 1), 2).value + 1
    
End Sub
```

The attached code is my add to table sub. value is the userform entry, generally a string, but I left it as a variant in case I get something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above mixes up cell ranges and listobject ranges. Work directly with the listobject and it should work.

```
Sub AddDataRow(tableName As String, value As Variant)

    Dim lastRow As ListRow
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim table As ListObject
    Dim col As Integer

    Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Jobs and Shifts")
    Set table = sheet.ListObjects(tableName)

    'First check if the last row is empty; if not, add a row
    If table.ListRows.Count > 0 Then

        Set lastRow = table.ListRows(table.ListRows.Count)
        If worksheetFunction.CountBlank(lastRow.Range) <> lastRow.Columns.Count

            Dim useRow as ListRow
            Set useRow = table.ListRows.Add

        Else

            set useRow = lastRow

        End If
        
    Else

        Set useRow = table.ListRows.Add

    End If

    useRow.Range(1,1).Value = value    
    useRow.Range(1,2).Value = useRow.Range(1,2).Offset(-1).Value +1 
    'apologies if I didn't interpret this correctly. hopefully you can adjust easily
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey thank you for this, much appreciated.  I noticed two things causing me errors.  I changed  `Set lastRow = table.ListRows(table.ListRows.Count)' to 'Set lastRow = table.ListRows(table.ListRows.Count).range` and removed `Range` from 
       `If worksheetFunction.CountBlank(lastRow.Range) <> lastRow.Columns.Count`
Everything seems to now work the way it should.  Thank you for the solution

Comment: @Dragonchicken - glad it worked. The reason you had to make those changes is because you left `lastRow` declared as Range. If you declare as `ListRow` code should work, now?